# Emit Flow via another suspend function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow, suspend

How can I have the flow collector below receive "hello"? The collector is calling `myFunction1()` which in turn calls `myFunction2()`. Both are suspend functions.

Currently nothing happens when I hit run and no flow is received. Am I missing something here?

```
CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
    val flowCollector = repo.myFunction1()
        .onEach { string ->
            Log.d("flow received: ", string)
        }
        .launchIn(GlobalScope)
}
```

```
class Repo {

    suspend fun myFunction1(): Flow<String> = flow {
        /*some code*/
        myFunction2()
    }

    suspend fun myFunction2(): Flow<String> = flow {
        /*some code*/
        emit("hello")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use [`emitAll`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/emit-all.html) function for your case:

```
fun myFunction1(): Flow<String> = flow {
    /*some code*/
    emitAll(myFunction2())
}

fun myFunction2(): Flow<String> = flow {
    /*some code*/
    emit("hello")
}
```

`emitAll` function collects all the values from the `Flow`, created by `myFunction2()` function and emits them to the collector.

And there is no reason to set a `suspend` modifier before each function, `flow` builder isn't `suspend`.

Comment: Thanks, this answer is working. I have suspend functions as i am running asynchronous code in myFunction1/2 (retrofit/room). If you believe there are more optimal ways i should be structuring the Repo class, any recommendation/articles would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a very specific reason the functions returning a `Flow` from your repo shouldn't be suspending (As the `flow{}` builder isn't suspending). Since the suspending operation is collecting (waiting for values to come out of it).

From the code you've provided you're looking for the `flatMapLatest` function. [Docs here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-latest.html)

```kotlin
class Repo {

  fun function1() = 
    flow {
      val value = doSomething()
      emit(value)
    }
    .flatMapLatest { emittedValue -> function2() }
  fun function2() = flow {...}
}
```

Comment: Just to backup this answer https://rules.sonarsource.com/kotlin/RSPEC-6309

Comment: I did not know about this website! That's super useful information over there!